# How do I configure Google Analytics API v3

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Facing error:

`Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?.....: (403) User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile.`

I have multiple accounts in analytics. I've added my *verylongxxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com* **to each** account *admin > view > user management* **with permissions** *edit, collaborate, read & analyze*.

What I do wrong?

// upd

the request is

```
$service->get(
    'ga:XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    '2014-05-25',
    '2014-06-24',
    'ga:visits'
)
```

And this XXXXXXXXXXXXX is project number in Google console.

Answer (score 0):

Set this permission on account level,it will automatically set all permission 
to your web property and view level .

```
  go to your analytics account
  Administration› User Management 
  and set Read & Analyze or as you wish, then Click Save.
```